# Predicate to find collection that contains a value

Tags: jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

I have an entity that has an collection of String:

```
@Entity
class A {
    @Column
    private Set<String> coll;
}
```

The sql to create the table is the following:

```
create table a (
  coll varchar(10)[]
);
```

In the database, I have one column containing the array in the form of `{myString1, myString2}`.

I'm trying to create a Predicate/Specification to find the entities whose collection `coll` contains a specific value. I can't find how to do it.

I've tried stuff like:

```
public Specification<A> filter(String val) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        builder.isMember(val, root.get("coll"))
    };
}
```

But it's not working. I've seen people mentionning joins with `root.join("coll")`, but it's not working either, probbaly because it's not a OneToMany relation, I have nothing to join on, I just have an array of String.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your CRUD operations work on persisting and returning the col1 value in your entities? The specification states it should be serialized to the column, so I don't know how it will work with a Varchar(10)[] in the database. JPA api touching querying over collections won't apply to a basic column mapping - so you are left with implementation specific functionality (Hibernate?) if it exists, or just a null/not null checks. If you want to make querying easier and portable, use an ElementCollection type that writes to a separate table